# How to make visible the locale in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, locale

I was wondering if I could make visible the chosen locale. I do (on windows),

```
>bin\initdb --locale=en-us --encoding=utf-8 -U postgres -W clus1
>bin\pg_ctl.exe -D clus1 -l logfile2 start
>psql -U postgres
postgres=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
  2022-03-07 21:15:07.56299+01

>bin\pg_ctl.exe -D clus1 -l logfile2 stop
>rmdir /s clus1
```

Now I choose another locale,

```
>bin\initdb --locale=nl-nl --encoding=utf-8 -U postgres -W clus1
>bin\pg_ctl.exe -D clus1 -l logfile2 start
>psql -U postgres
postgres=# select now();
              now
-------------------------------
 2022-03-07 21:16:30.071371+01
```

I thought now() would be in Dutch, but is isn't. Why not, and how can I make the locale visible, so check the chosen locale?

Comment: Function names aren't translated. try `select now() as nu;`

Comment: In `psql` do: `show lc_ctype ;`. Also it should be `--locale=nl_NL` and `--locale=en_US`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locale consists of several parts:

- `lc_collate`: the rules to compare and sort strings
- `lc_ctype`: the rules to determine what type a character is (letter, digit, space, ...)
- `lc_messages`: the language for error and log messages
- `lc_monetary`: the language to use for currency format codes in `to_char` for numbers

  To see the effect of `lc_monetary`, try

  ```
  SELECT to_char(100, '999L');
  ```
- `lc_numeric`: the language to use for decimal comma and group separator format codes in `to_char` for numbers

  To see the effect of `lc_numeric`, try

  ```
  SELECT to_char(1000000.50, '9G999G999D00L');
  ```
- `lc_time`: the language to use for week day and month name format codes in `to_char` for timestamps, `log_filename` and such

  To see the effect of `lc_numeric`, try

  ```
  SELECT to_char(current_timestamp, 'FMDAY, DD. FMMONTH');
  ```

You can find the setting of each of them with `SHOW`:

```
SHOW lc_collate;
```

The type output functions for date/time and numeric data types don't use the locale settings, so the output of `now()` not affected by the locale.

Comment: Thank you. But I am not so interested what show gives. I would like to know how you can see for example lc_time in your data when you query. I did 'select now();' but I saw no difference when I change the locale from en-US to nl-NL for example.

Comment: I added examples and clarification.